# How to install a old QT version at archlinux？

Tags: c++, linux, qt, archlinux

I had installed QT5 by pacman long ago.

```
qmake -v          
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /usr/lib
```

And I want to install QT 5.5.1,so I had downloaded **qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.7z** and follow the Readme.
This is final result:

```
make[3]: *** [Makefile:21908: .obj/qsslcertificate_openssl.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/chippy/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src/network'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:192: sub-network-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/chippy/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:46: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/chippy/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1/qtbase'
make: *** [Makefile:73: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

And then I downloaded **qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run** to run at shell:

```
$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run                      
static QPlatformTheme* QKdeTheme::createKdeTheme(): Unable to determine KDE dirs
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ERR_free_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_new_null
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_push
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay_version
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
Could not register file downloader for https protocol: QSslSocket::supportsSsl() returns false
[7] Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
[8] Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
[1]    17534 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.5.1.run
```

I cannot understand the error out and I don't know if this is the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: This question might be better asked over at [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), I'm sure you'll probably find a question that's already been asked over there

Comment: Remove the previous qt and then install a new one .

Answer (score 1):

Remove the previous qt and then install a new one . See this about [Removing Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html#updating-or-removing-qt)

you should go to the path that installed Qt , and then Run **Maintenance Tool** .exe file. then after uninstall previous , install new one .